# Python - Get FP/TP from Confusion Matrix using a List

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I using two different classifiers to predict a binary target (Random Forests and Decision Trees). Now I want to evaluate my model creating a confusion matrix. For example, for predicting the binary value using random forests I've:

```
training_features, test_features, training_target, test_target, = train_test_split(df.drop(['score_goal'], axis=1),
                                              df['score_goal'],
                                              test_size = .3,
                                              random_state=12)

clf_rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=25, random_state=12)
clf_rf.fit(training_features, training_target)
print("Accuracy using Random Forest Classifier is ", clf_rf.score(test_features, test_target)*100)
```

I'm confusing because I don't know how I can compare the predicted values to identify how many False Positives, etc. I have.

Anyone knows how can I build that function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using scikit-learn. So why not explore a bit more? Scikit has a `metrics` module, that can be of use for your problem. Essentially, what you need is to have two separate arrays - one with real labels and another with predicted labels. And then you're good to go, you could call `metrics.classification_report` or `metrics.confusion_matrix` or `metrics.accuracy_score`, all of them use the real labels and the predicted labels.

There's nothing wrong with using `clf_rf.score(test_features, test_target)`, but it will only give you a single value. If you look at the source code, what happens is that the `score` method calls a `predict` method with `test_feature` for prediction of labels, which occurs behind the scenes.

It's better to actually capture those predicted labels, so that you can reuse them.

```
clf_rf.fit(training_features, training_target)
predicted_target = clf_rf.predict(test_features)
accuracy = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(test_target, predicted_target)
cnf_matrix = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(test_target, predicted_target)
class_report = sklearn.metrics.classification_report(test_target, predicted_target)
```

And then you could do whichever you like with the calculated metrics, print, plot, etc. 
Have a look at the examples that are included for each model/metrics you're using [1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#examples-using-sklearn-ensemble-randomforestclassifier), [2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix), [3](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py), [4](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report), etc.